# touchesShouldBegin Returns NO in ScrollView: Then What?

Tags: objective-c, uikit, uiscrollview

I'm getting exactly the behavior I want in a `UIScrollView`: when I return `NO` for `touchesShouldBegin`, the scrolling behavior happens. Otherwise, the content views get the event.

However, I'd like to show something on touch down and touch up when the scrolling behavior is occurring. Unfortunately, returning NO for `touchesShouldBegin` blocks the `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` methods.

The delegate method:

```
-(void) scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
```

doesn't work because sometimes the user touches but doesn't drag. How can I register touchUp and touchDown events yet preserve scrolling behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. While a UIScrollview is scrolling, the subview(s) (and the view itself) are not updated or redrawn. It only scrolls. It is just how the UIResponder chain works in this scenario.